# strtol resulting in a segmentation fault on the raspberry pi 3 b+

Tags: c, string, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, string.h

I have this problem that strtol doesn't work and results in my C program crashing. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 b+ but that probably doesn't matter.

My program (which is a command line tool to control shift registers) uses strtol for parsing through the command line arguments the program gets.

Here's the output I get: `fish: Job 2, “./a.out -p 16 -w 0xff” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Addroundary error)`

And here's the output on gdp:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_____strtol_l_internal (
    nptr=0x76f72968 <_nl_C_LC_CTYPE_toupper+512> "", 
    nptr@entry=0x7efff6e9 "16", endptr=0x7efff6e9, 
    base=<optimized out>, group=group@entry=0, 
    loc=0x76fa1c70 <_nl_global_locale>) at strtol_l.c:484
484     strtol_l.c: No such file or directory.
```

The following is the code:

```c
else if(!strcmp(argv[arg], "-p") || !strcmp(argv[arg], "-pins")) {
     if(argc <= arg+1)
         return 1;

     pins = strtol(argv[++arg], endptr, 0);
}
```

The command line argument parsing happens like so:

```c
uint8_t arg, pins;
char **endptr;
uint64_t writeValue;
bool valueGiven; // The other bools that I define are irrelevant

for(arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
    if(!strcmp(argv[arg], "-w") || !strcmp(argv[arg], "-write")) {
        if(argc <= arg+1)
            return 1;

        writeValue = strtol(argv[++arg], endptr, 0); // error happens here too

        valueGiven = true;
    }

    else if(!strcmp(argv[arg], "-p") || !strcmp(argv[arg], "-pins")) {
        if(argc <= arg+1)
            return 1;

        pins = strtol(argv[++arg], endptr, 0);
    }

    // There are more arguments but those are irrelevant
}
```

And I run the program like this: `./a.out -p 16 -w 0xFF`

This error is very odd for the exact same thing worked before, could this be a case of data corruption?

Comment: I doubt you have provided enough information for a meaningful diagnosis. Do I understand correctly that it went into an `if` that it shouldn't have? Your command line does not seem to contain a `-p`. If that's the case, there's little point in investigating `strtol`, your real problem happened earlier.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: The `endptr` argument looks suspicious...

Comment: If you have: `char *endptr;` somewhere, you probably want: `pins = strtol(argv[++arg], &endptr, 0);`

Comment: @dratenik it does go to the correct if I believe, for I have tested it with various printf and puts calls :D. I myself believe that the problem is in strtol for it crashes in that exact line where strtol is called. Also, gdp reports that the problem is in strtol, it specifically says that `strtol_l.c: No such file or directory`. I will remind everyone that this exact code worked before, but something odd seems to have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `char **endptr` is uninitialized.  It needs to point to a `char *` where the address of the first unconverted character will be stored.  Instead, yours points nowhere, so `strtol` is going to try to write to whatever bogus memory location it points to, and very likely crash.

GCC and clang should both issue warnings about the uninitialized variable if you enable `-Wall`.  [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/8qj45PdTM). Always use compiler warnings, and don't ignore them!

Normally you would declare a `char *` variable and pass its address:

```
char *end;
strtol(argv[++arg], &end, 0);
```

Comment: Nit, would use `endptr` to stay consistent with man page description `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I like it better this way.  `endptr` is the name of the argument to `strtol`, and what I am passing is indeed a pointer to `end`.  I think to really be consistent, one would write `char *end; char **endptr = &end; strtol(argv[++arg], endptr, 0);` but the extra variable is redundant.

Comment: No worries, just a suggestion, that's why I added "Nit" and `:)` Completely up to you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I personally named it "endptr".
PS: Thanks for the help Nate!

Comment: Note that you can pass NULL if you do not intend to use the value of `end` afterwards